# What is the meaning of this expression?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]
What's the meaning of cos x >_ U[ 2npi - pi/2 , 2npi + pi/2]
And what does U denote?

Comment: Its a Union sign.

Comment: It means that if $\cos x \ge0$ then $x$ must belong to the set formed by taking the union of those intervals.

Comment: A reason it is better for a book to use words (like "if, then") rather than symbols (like "$\Longrightarrow$").  Instead of "Domain $\rightarrow R$" write "The domain is $R$".

Comment: Think of the unit circle plotted on a Cartesian graph. $x=\cos\theta$, so $cos\theta \ge 0$ for all values on and to the right of the y-axis. $2n\pi$ comes from the fact that $2\pi$ is the period of the cosine function.

Answer (score 2):

U denotes union.  This is read: cosx is greater than or equal to zero implies x is an element of the union [2npi-pi/2,2npi+pi/2] for all integers n.

So, for example, if you substitute n=1, you have cos x is greater than or equal to zero for [2pi-pi/2, 2pi+pi/2]  which is true.  The sentence is stating that this interval will hold when you substitute for any integer n.

Comment: Well union doesn't make sense if it is an interval. An interval already means all the values between the limits will be included. Example [2pi-pi/2, 2pi+pi/2] already includes the numbers between these two numbers. Why is union needed? What if I dont use it?

Comment: In this case, the union refers to the union of all such intervals that satisfy [2npi-pi/2,2npi+pi/2].  So, the union would look like this: [2pi-pi/2,2pi+pi/2]u[4pi-pi/2,4pi+pi/2]u[6pi-pi/2,6pi+pi/2].......